# How to requeue messages in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp

After the consumer gets a message, consumer/worker does  some validations and then call web service. In this phase, if any error occurs or validation fails, we want the message put back to the queue it was originally consumed from.

I have read RabbitMQ documentation. But I am confused about differences between reject, nack and cancel methods.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Short answer:**

To requeue specific message you can pick both `basic.reject` or `basic.nack` with `multiple` flag set to false.

`basic.consume` calling may also results to messages redelivering if you are using message acknowledge and there are un-acknowledged message on consumer at specific time and consumer exit without ack-ing them.

`basic.recover` will redeliver all un-acked messages on specific channel.

**Long answer:**

[`basic.reject`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.reject) and [`basic.nack`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.nack) both serves to same purpose - drop or requeue message that can't be handled by specific consumer (at the given moment, under certain conditions or at all). The main difference between them is that `basic.nack` supports bulk messages processing, whilst `basic.reject` doesn't.

This difference described in [Negative Acknowledgements](http://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html) article on official RabbitMQ web site:

> The AMQP specification defines the `basic.reject` method that allows clients to reject individual, delivered messages, instructing the broker to either discard them or requeue them. Unfortunately, `basic.reject` provides no support for negatively acknowledging messages in bulk.
>
> To solve this, RabbitMQ supports the `basic.nack` method that provides all the functionality of `basic.reject` whilst **also allowing for bulk processing of messages**.
>
> To reject messages in bulk, clients set the `multiple` flag of the `basic.nack` method to `true`. The broker will then reject all unacknowledged, delivered messages up to and including the message specified in the `delivery_tag` field of the `basic.nack` method. In this respect, [`basic.nack`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.nack) complements the bulk acknowledgement semantics of [`basic.ack`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.ack).

Note, that `basic.nack` method is RabbitMQ-specific extension while `basic.reject` method is part of AMQP 0.9.1 specification.

As to [`basic.cancel`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.cancel) method, it used to notify server that client stops message consuming. Note, that client may receive arbitrary messages number between `basic.cancel` method sending an receiving the `cancel-ok` reply. If message acknowledge is used by client and it has any un-acknowledged messages they will be moved back to the queue they originally was consumed from.

[`basic.recover`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#basic.recover) has some limitations in RabbitMQ: it 
 - [basic.recover with requeue=false](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-errata.html#section_2)
 - [basic.recover synchronicity](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-errata.html#section_28)

In addition to errata, [according to RabbitMQ specs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html) `basic.recover` has partial support (Recovery with requeue=false is not supported.)

**Note about [`basic.consume`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.consume):**

When [`basic.consume`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.consume) started without auto-ack (`no­ack=false`) and there are some pending messages non-acked messages, then when consumer get canceled (dies, fatal error, exception, whatever) that pending messages will be redelivered. Technically, that pending messages will not be processed (even dead-lettered) until consumer release them (ack/nack/reject/recover). Only after that they will be processed (e.g. deadlettered).

For example, let say we post originally 5 message in a row:

```
Queue(main) (tail) { [4] [3] [2] [1] [0] } (head)
```

And then consume 3 of them, but not ack them, and then cancel consumer. We will have this situation:

```
Queue(main) (tail) { [4] [3] [2*] [1*] [0*] } (head)
```

where star (`*`) notes that `redelivered` flag set to `true`.

Assume that we have situation with dead-lettered exchange set and queue for dead-lettered messages

```
Exchange(e-main)                                   Exchange(e-dead) 
  Queue(main){x-dead-letter-exchange: "e-dead"}       Queue(dead)
```

And assume we post 5 message with `expire` property set to `5000` (5 sec):

```
Queue(main) (tail) { [4] [3] [2] [1] [0] } (head)
Queue(dead) (tail) { }(head)
```

and then we consume 3 message from `main` queue and hold them for 10 second:

```
Queue(main) (tail) { [2!] [1!] [0!] } (head)
Queue(dead) (tail) { [4*] [3*] } (head)
```

where exclamation mark (`!`) stands for unacked message. Such messages can't be delivered to any consumer and they normally can't be viewed in management panel. But let's cancel consumer, remember, that it still hold 3 un-acked message:

```
Queue(main) (tail) { } (head)
Queue(dead) (tail) { [2*] [1*] [0*] [4*] [3*] } (head)
```

So now that 3 messages which was in the head put back to original queue, but as they has per-message TTL set, they are dead-lettered to the tail of dead-letter queue (sure, via dead-letter exchange).

**P.S.:**

Consuming message aka listening for new one is somehow different from direct queue access (getting one or more message without taking care of others). See [`basic.get`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.get) method description for more.

Comment: If basic.nack is exactly like basic.reject but supports bulk messages processing, when is basic.reject preferred over basic.nack? Why don't one just use basic.nack in all situations then?

Comment: [`basic.nack`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html) is RabbitMQ-specific extension.

Comment: by "RabbitMQ-specific extension" you mean outside of the extension is not used? Meaning if I used Spring AMQP to integrate with RabbitMQ then I can't use basic.nack?

Comment: I mean that `basic.nack` is not part of AMQP standard and is RabbitMQ specific extension (I added note about this to answer to make it visible for further readers). If you use RabbitMQ as AMQP broker, `basic.nack` can be used instead of `basic.reject`.

Comment: `basic.consume calling may also results to messages redelivering if you are using message acknowledge and there are un-acknowledged message on consumer at specific time.` Is this statement correct?? AFAIK, if ACK is not received, the message will wait until it reaches TTL.

Comment: @NeoWang yeah, I probably mean that if `basic.consume` started with without auto-ack (`no­ack=false`) and there are some pending messages non-acked messages then when consumer get canceled (dies, fatal error, exception, whatever) that pending messages will be redelivered. Technically, that pending messages will not be processed (even dead-lettered) until consumer release them (ack/nack/reject/recover). Only after that they will be processed (e.g. dedlettered). But thanks for pointing on this ambiguity in original answer, I will add this explanation and example.

Comment: Even though `basic.reject` is supposed to be standardised, I have observed other implementations handling it differently to RabbitMQ.