# How to Nak a ServiceStack RabbitMQ message within the RegisterHandler?

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

I'd like to be able to requeue a message from within my Service Endpoint that has been wired up through the RegisterHandler method of RabbitMQ Server. e.g.

```
mqServer.RegisterHandler<OutboundILeadPhone>(m =>
{
    var db = container.Resolve<IFrontEndRepository>();
    db.SaveMessage(m as Message);
    return ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(m);
}, noOfThreads: 1);
```

or here.

```
public object Post(OutboundILeadPhone request)
{
    throw new OutBoundAgentNotFoundException(); // added after mythz posted his first response
}
```

I don't see any examples how this is accomplished, so I'm starting to believe that it may not be possible with the ServiceStack abstraction. On the other hand, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107913/) looks promising.

Thank you, Stephen

**Update**

Throwing an exception in the Service does nak it, but then the message is sent to the OutboundILeadPhone.dlq which is normal ServiceStack behavior. Guess what I'm looking for is a way for the message to stay in the OutboundILeadPhone.inq queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing an exception in your Service will [automatically Nak the message](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/6ac538ead6cb9980f1d7d24a4c6fd601a06df177/src/ServiceStack/Messaging/MessageHandler.cs#L119). This default exception handling behavior can also be overridden with RabbitMqServer's `RegisterHandler` API that takes an `Exception` callback, i.e:

```
void RegisterHandler<T>(
    Func<IMessage<T>, object> processMessageFn, 
    Action<IMessage<T>, Exception> processExceptionEx);

void RegisterHandler<T>(
    Func<IMessage<T>, object> processMessageFn, 
    Action<IMessage<T>, Exception> processExceptionEx, 
    int noOfThreads)
```

Comment: @Stephen It only sends to dlq after a retry attempt also failed. You'll need to use the register API's above to [override the default exception handling](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/6ac538ead6cb9980f1d7d24a4c6fd601a06df177/src/ServiceStack/Messaging/MessageHandler.cs#L105), i.e. to always `requeue`.

Comment: @Stephen Just `0` or `1` is [valid for RabbitMQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#messages-that-generate-exceptions-can-be-re-tried-then-published-to-the-dead-letter-queue-dlq) since RabbitMQ messages only contain a boolean `Redelivered` instead of a number of redelivery attempts.